# Why someone prefer to define class method as `module SomeModule extend self` but not `class SomeClass ; def self.method`?

Tags: ruby

I am writing Ruby code.

The code before refactoring looks like:

```
class Tool
   def self.say_hi
     return "hi"
   end 
end
```

and after refactored by my workmates:

```
module Tool
   extend self 
   def say_hi
     return "hi"
   end
end
```

both style of code can work as:  `Tool.say_hi`.

I want to know what's the pros and cons for his style. thanks.

Comment: Have a look at [`module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/Module.html#method-i-module_function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have changed the class for a module, the main difference is that modules can be included in other class to reuse that `say_hi` method.

```
class Toolbox
  include Tool
end

Toolbox.new.say_hi
```

But I don't know if that was the main driver for the refactor, another difference between the two approaches is that you can control the visibility  of the method with the second snippet.

```
module Tool
  extend self

  private
  def say_hi
    return "hi"
  end
end

Tool.say_hi
```

Will return `private method 'say_hi' called for Tool:Module (NoMethodError` meanwhile this would just work.

```
class Tool

  private
  def self.say_hi
    return "hi"
  end
end
Tool.say_hi
```